# displaying text and an image in one line (inline)

Tags: html

I have a logobar I'd like to have at the top of my website.
I want this to be a simple text with an image next to it.

I'm using the following code but the image displays underneath the text.
I am using a div which has both the text and image in a list which I've set to inline but they are not displaying in one line.

```
<doctype! html>
<html>

<head>
    <title> Breaditt </title>
    <style>
html, body {
font-family: sans-serif;
margin: 0;
padding: 0; }


#logobar {
background: rgb(206, 211, 255);
display: inline-block; }

#logobar ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0; }

#logobar li {
display: inline; }


#logobar p {
font-size: 18;
font-family: Comic sans MS; }






    </style>
</head>


<body>

    <div id="logobar">
        <ul>
        <li><p> Breaditt </p></li>
        <li><img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="breaditt cat" width="100"     height="100"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Just to let you know, that's not how you declare doctype. `<!DOCTYPE html>` is the right way in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the paragraph around your text. The paragraph is block element and it will break the line:

```
<div id="logobar">
    <ul>
        <li>Breaditt</li>
        <li><img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="breaditt cat" width="100"     height="100"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Another option is to inline the paragraph as well:

```
#logobar p {
    font-size: 18;
    font-family: Comic sans MS; 
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I removed the <p>'s

Comment: Ok, happy to help. Please remember to accept / up vote the answer that solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
#logobar li {
    display: inline;
}
```

to

```
#logobar li {
    float: left;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/WKLmG/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

No need to use list. Try:

```
<div id="logobar">
   <p> Breaditt </p>
   <img src="img/logo.jpg" alt="breaditt cat" width="100"     height="100">
</div>
```

with CSS:

```
#logobar>* {
display: inline; }
```

[Example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/WkMSW/)